# Python cycle only returns last value

Tags: python, python-2.7

My english can be bad, so I'm sorry

HI.  I have some troubles with python cycle. My script counts all weekdays between two dates and for each of days copies all text from x.txt  to textfile.txt, inserting date in the beginning of text. x is few textfiles numbered from 1 to n.   For example starting date is 1,1,2017, end date is 5,1,2017. 1.txt contains aaa, 2.txt is bbb, 3.txt is ccc and so on.  Output file should be:

```
2017-01-02 (because 1 January is Sunday which is weekend)

aaa

2017-01-03

bbb

2017-01-04

ccc

2017-01-05

ddd
```

But it looks like

```
2017-01-05

aaa

2017-01-05

bbb

2017-01-05

ccc (only 3 files are processed, should be 4 and only last date is inserted everywhere)
```

I added `print n` trying to trace where problem is, and after `for x in range (1, n):` it gives me

```
2
3
3
4
4
4
```

Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import shutil
import os


def dc(d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, y2):
    start = datetime(y1, m1, d1)
    end = datetime(y2, m2, d2)
    delta = timedelta(days=1)
    d = start
    n = 1
    weekend = ([5, 6])
    while d <= end:
        if d.weekday() not in weekend:
            with open('textfile.txt','wb') as destination:
                for x in range (1, n):
                    print n
                    with open(str(x) + '.txt','rb') as source:
                        destination.write(str(d)[:10])
                        destination.write(os.linesep)
                        shutil.copyfileobj(source, destination)
                        destination.write(os.linesep*2)
        n += 1
        d += delta

dc(1,1,2017,5,1,2017)
```

So main question is: how do i get this working as planned?

And some other questions

1. How can i store input data in other way? Having 30 text files is OK for me, but in future I want to choose input source, and having like 5 folders with 30 files in each of them would make it hard to organize them. Maybe i can use lists or something?
2. how can i reformat the date which is written in output file? yyyy-mm-dd is fine, but i prefer dd-mm-yyyy
3. this script will work with n=30 most of the time, but if n<30, i'd like that  last 5 copied files always  would be 25.txt-30.txt 
   I'll be glad to hear any suggestions. thanks for the help

Comment: Please fix indentation in your code. It is not correct now.

Answer (score 0):

You should have either used 'while' loop or a 'for' loop.

```
x = 0
with open('textfile.txt','wb') as destination:
    while d <= end:
        if d.weekday() not in weekend:
            with open(str(x) + '.txt','rb') as source:
                #<Do your stuff>
            #Next line will not skip any file
            x += 1
        #if you want to skip files as you move, use next line (remove '#') and remove the above line.
        #x+=1
        delta+=1
```

P.S. I am not sure if leaving your files open will create any problem i.e.  programmers generally close their files after use.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! I will try that

Comment: Please fix your indentation Ajay

Comment: Unfortunately I can not make this work. maybe i need to rewrite code the other way

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm sure that you still need to include the with open function before your while function... It kinda does what you want except it prints  something like this... http://pastebin.com/X0KwKdmU

Comment: I forgot to mention that this in still work in progress. I didn't want to leave this issue for too long...

Comment: Ok, change n = 1 to n = 0, remove n += 1 and put the x +=1 underneath the if statement

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to initialise the n variable

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Also, there is no need of x variable if the user do not want to track the number of files used.

Comment: Actually you do need the x variable because part of the for loop is incremnting to the next file. X also needs to be equal to 1.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was supposed to be x=0, but I guess everyone makes mistakes sometimes :)